# How to change www.domain.com/photos/public/gallery to www.domain.com/photos/ in .htaccess file?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've installed a photo script in a sub-folder(photos) on my site.

The script doesn't work when I go to `www.domain.com/photos/` only works when i go to `www.domain.com/photos/public/gallery/`.

Can someone please help me with the code I would use in my `.htaccess` file to have `www.domain.com/photos/` as the main link?

Thank You

Comment: What about posting some code?

Comment: This is going to be a wonky rewrite. The folder `public` should not be in your webroot, it should _be_ your webroot.

Comment: What code should I post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/photos/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /aviation-photos/

RewriteRule ^$ public/gallery [L]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava I tried this code but got the following error in my browser: "This webpage has a redirect loop" Any other ideas?

Comment: That didn't work.  Here's the actual link to the site: [link](http://www.flightschoollist.com/aviation-photos/public/gallery)  I just changed the 'RewriteBase /photos/' to 'RewriteBase /aviation-photos/'

Comment: ok based on that link I edited code again. Try it now.

Comment: Tried it and got the same redirect loop error.

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess in your system anywhere?

Comment: Yes, in the root directory.

Comment: Ok can you place content of both .htaccess files in your question.

Comment: Had some folders moved around and it now works. Thanks for all your help anubhava.

Comment: That's great, glad it worked out finally.